# installing nvidia driver on archLinux and mining dogecoin

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia

I have a GeForce GTX660 and I'm trying to install the latest nvidia driver to ultimately be able to mine dogecoins with these [installation instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nvidia#Alternate_install:_custom_kernel)

It says to put my kernel version in my PKGBUILD and nvidia.install file. From uname -r I get 3.12.8-1-ARCH but it can't find /usr/lib/modules/extramodules-3.12.8-1-ARCH/version when I run makepkg -ci but extramodules-3.12-ARCH exists.  So I just set it to 3.12-ARCH and installed the package.

`cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` gives me the output:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  331.38  Wed Jan  8 19:32:30 PST 2014
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.2 20131219 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

However running `nvidia-smi` gives me:

`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure      that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Running `cudaminer` gives me:
`Unable to query CUDA driver version! Is an nVidia driver installed?`
I also tried running it with the official nvidia-304xx driver but that didn't work either.

Also tried just removing nvidia drivers and installing the official nvidia package with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to run cudaminer through ssh which is why it couldn't find my video card... I was able to run it locally fine. Stupid me.  However, is it possible to run it through ssh?